# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, django

here is header.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Includes -->

<script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/myHeader.module.js' %}"></script>

<body ng-app="myHeader">
    <div ng-controller="HeaderController">
          <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

here is myHeader.module.js

```
var myHeader = angular.module('myHeader', []);

myHeader.controller('HeaderController' , ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.message = "hello";

}])
```

i am trying to use the above module file but it throws me the error

```
Failed to instantiate module myHeader due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/nomod?p0=myHe...
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:6:412
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:25:235
    at b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:24:282)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:25:20
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:39:374
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:39:222)
    at db (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:43:246)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:21:19
```

> and also it is not able to include the js file...it says 404 not found
>   though it is placed in the corresponding folder

what can be the reason and how can i get over with it?

Comment: As your saying its all with your script inclusion,try to make it call properly.....i think you will be done with that

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: you mentioned that myHeader.module.js giving 404 not found.so what i am saying is try to fix that first....the error occurring may be because of this .....

Comment: i m sure why it is throwing that error though the file is placed in that folder only

Answer (score 1):

The reason should be somewhere else. The code provided *works*

```js
var myHeader = angular.module('myHeader', []);

myHeader.controller('HeaderController' , ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.message = "hello";

}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myHeader">
    <div ng-controller="HeaderController">
          <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

The problem is certainly linked to this line

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/myHeader.module.js' %}"></script>
```

Make sure that the `src` is the correct one